# Why does rqt_plot plot the velocity obtained from /join_states at negative time values?

Tags: joint-state-publisher, rqt-plot, use-sim-time

I am trying to get a transient process of changing the speed of the wheel to which I am giving a command signal using rqt_plot, but for some reason the time takes negative values along the abscissa axis, although the command graph is displayed at a positive time. What could it be?
[image]
Launch file:

```py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PythonExpression
from launch.substitutions import ThisLaunchFileDir


from launch_ros.actions import Node
import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Specify the name of the package and path to xacro file within the package
    pkg_name = 'beginning'
    file_subpath = 'urdf/rover_1.xacro'

    urdf_tutorial_path = get_package_share_directory(pkg_name)
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(urdf_tutorial_path, 'rviz', 'urdf1.rviz')

    # Use xacro to process the file
    xacro_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(pkg_name),file_subpath)
    robot_description_raw = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()

    
    world_path = LaunchConfiguration('world')
    world_path_declare = DeclareLaunchArgument('world', default_value='',description='World to open')

    # Configure the node
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description_raw,
        'use_sim_time': True}] # add other parameters here if required
    )

    gui = DeclareLaunchArgument('gui', default_value='true',
                              description='Set to "false" to run headless.')

    server = DeclareLaunchArgument('server', default_value='true',
                              description='Set to "false" not to run gzserver.')
    
    delay = DeclareLaunchArgument('delay', default_value='0')

    # GAZEBO

    include_server = IncludeLaunchDescription(PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/gzserver.launch.py']),
                                                condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('server')),
                                                launch_arguments={'world': world_path,}.items())
    include_client = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                                                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([ThisLaunchFileDir(), '/gzclient.launch.py']),
                                                condition=IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui')))

    print('CHECKPOINT1')

    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                    arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                '-entity', 'my_bot',
                                '-z','5'],
                    output='screen')
    
    joint_state_publisher = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True}]
    )

    # RVIZ
    
    rviz = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', default_rviz_config_path],
    )

    timer_spawn = TimerAction(period = '0', actions=[spawn_entity])

    # CONTROL

    left_wheel_1_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["left_wheel_1"],
    )

    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster"],
    )



    # Run the node
    return LaunchDescription([
        world_path_declare,
        gui,
        server,
        include_server,
        include_client,
        node_robot_state_publisher,
        left_wheel_1_spawner,
        joint_broad_spawner,
        timer_spawn,
        rviz,
        # joint_state_publisher
    ])
```

Controllers config:

```yaml
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100
    use_sim_time: true

    left_wheel_1:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster


left_wheel_1:
  ros__parameters:
    joints: [base_to_left_1_wheel]
        
    command_interfaces:
      - velocity
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

joint_state_broadcaster:
  ros__parameters:
    use_local_topics: true
```

Robot URDF:

```xml
<robot name="rover" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
  </material>

  <xacro:property name="wheel_rad" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="wheel_len" value="0.1" />
  <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="1" />

  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="prefix reflect y_reflect">
    <link name="${prefix}_wheel">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder length="${wheel_len}" radius="${wheel_rad}"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" xyz="0 ${y_reflect*wheel_len/2} 0"/>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="${wheel_len}" radius="${wheel_rad}"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" xyz="0 ${y_reflect*wheel_len/2} 0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
          <mass value="${wheel_mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${wheel_mass*(3*wheel_rad*wheel_rad+wheel_len*wheel_len)/12}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${wheel_mass*wheel_rad*wheel_rad/2}" iyz="0.0" izz="${wheel_mass*(3*wheel_rad*wheel_rad+wheel_len*wheel_len)/12}"/>
        </inertial>

    </link>

    <joint name="base_to_${prefix}_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="${prefix}_wheel"/>
        <dynamics damping="0.1" friction="0.1"/>
        <origin xyz="${reflect*(0.5)} ${y_reflect*0.3}  -0.15" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- A bunch of stuff cut -->
  </xacro:macro>



  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 0.6 0.3"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="1 0.6 0.3"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="30"/>
      <inertia ixx="${30*(1+0.3*0.3)/12}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${30*(0.6*0.6+0.3*0.3)/12}" iyz="0.0" izz="${30*(1+0.6*0.6)/12}"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="imu_base" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="imu_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

  <link name="imu_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="camera_holder_base" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="camera_holder"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_holder">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.5" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.25"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="camera_base" type="fixed">
    <parent link="camera_holder"/>
    <child link="camera_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" />
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="Logo_base" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="logo"/>
    <origin xyz="0.45 0 0.15" />
  </joint>

  <link name="logo">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
  </link>



  <xacro:wheel prefix="left_1" reflect="-1" y_reflect="1"/>
  <xacro:wheel prefix="left_2" reflect="0" y_reflect="1"/>
  <xacro:wheel prefix="left_3" reflect="1" y_reflect="1"/>
  <xacro:wheel prefix="right_1" reflect="-1" y_reflect="-1"/>
  <xacro:wheel prefix="right_2" reflect="0" y_reflect="-1"/>
  <xacro:wheel prefix="right_3" reflect="1" y_reflect="-1"/>

  <xacro:include filename="gazebo.xacro" />
  <!--xacro:include filename="rover_control.xacro" /-->
  <xacro:include filename="controll.xacro" />

</robot>
```

Gazebo.xacro

```xml
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="left_1_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="left_2_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="left_3_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="right_1_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="right_2_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="right_3_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>



    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher"
            filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
            <update_rate>20</update_rate>
            <joint_name>base_to_left_1_wheel</joint_name>
            <joint_name>base_to_left_2_wheel</joint_name>
            <joint_name>base_to_left_3_wheel</joint_name>
            <joint_name>base_to_right_1_wheel</joint_name>
            <joint_name>base_to_right_2_wheel</joint_name>
            <joint_name>base_to_right_3_wheel</joint_name>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="imu_link">
        <gravity>true</gravity>
        <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
            <always_on>true</always_on>
            <update_rate>100</update_rate>
            <visualize>true</visualize>
            <!--topic>__default_topic__</topic-->
            <plugin name="imu_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" >
                <ros>
                    <remapping>~/out:=imu</remapping>
                </ros>
                <topicName>mumu</topicName>
                <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
                <updateRateHZ>10.0</updateRateHZ>
                <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
                <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
                <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
                <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
                <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
            </plugin>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="camera_link">
        <sensor type="camera" name="camera1">
        <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <camera name="head">
            <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
            <width>800</width>
            <height>800</height>
            <format>R8G8B8</format>
            </image>
            <clip>
            <near>0.02</near>
            <far>300</far>
            </clip>
            <noise>
            <type>gaussian</type>
            <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
                That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
                channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>0.007</stddev>
            </noise>
        </camera>
            <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
                <cameraName>rrbot/camera1</cameraName>
                <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
                <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
                <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
                <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
                <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
                <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
                <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
                <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
                <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
            </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

    

    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_joint_pose_trajectory"
            filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_pose_trajectory.so">
            <update_rate>2</update_rate>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>



</robot>
```

Controll.xacro

```xml
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <ros2_control name="Gazebosystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>

        <joint name="base_to_left_1_wheel">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>

    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
            <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
            <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
            <parameters>$(find beginning)/config/rover_controllers1.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>
```